# Sub2ind Out of range subscript

Tags: matlab, matrix, coordinates, line

I tried to use sub2ind function in matlab in order to get a vector from a matrix which represent a linear function that I want to extract like in the following exemple :

Matrix M :

```
01 02 03 04 05
06 07 08 09 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25
```

Linear function that I use to represent the vector that I want to extract from matrix. I would like to turn around the center so I start with a slope of 0 and I increment until 90°.

```
slope = 20;  Approx. 3°
y = slope * x
```

And I would like this output :

```
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
```

Or directly this vector :

```
V = {22, 18, 13, 08, 04}
```

So, I wrote this code in matlab :

```
M = zeros(201);
x = -1:0.01:1;
y = 20 * x;
sub2ind(size(m), y, x);
```

And I got the following error :

```
Error using sub2ind
Out of range subscript.
```

I checked size of x, y, and M, and it should work...

Comment: Your x and y are not even integers, of course sub2ind would complain. You of course need to compute the row and column indices first. In your example, you'd need `row = [5,4,3,2,1]; col = [1, 2, 2, 3];`

Comment: Yes, I read the documentation again, and I understand what sub2ind is waiting for now. But I've got the same problem again, that is how to determine row and col from my linear function ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform your coordinates, which assume 0 is the middle of the array, to proper indices, which start at 1 at the left and the top of the array. You also need to round the coordinates to be indices, and remove duplicates. This bit of code does these things:

```matlab
x = -1:0.01:1;
y = 20 * x;

x = x + 100; % Let’s assume (100,100) are the indices of your origin.
y = y + 100;

coords = round([x.', y.']);
coords = max(1, coords); % just in case some are too low
coords = min(size(M), coords); % just in case some are too high
coords = unique(coords, 'rows');

V = M(sub2ind(size(M), coords(:,2), coords(:,1)));
```